Supabase Multiple onConflicts in upsert query
When upserting to my table, i have two constrains that I both want to add an onConflict for. I will be upserting data that conflicts with either of the two, but never both.
The constrains on the table are:
    constraint patients_pkey primary key (id),
    constraint patients_id_key unique (id),
    constraint patients_source_foreign_id_unique unique (source, foreign_id),

So I tried:
const { data, error } = await supabase
            .from('patients')
            .upsert(
                {
                    id: patient.id ?? undefined,
                    belongs_to_user: user.id,
                    belongs_to_clinic: clinic.id,
                    name: patient.name,
                    identification_number: patient.identification_number,
                    notes: patient.notes,
                    source: patient.source,
                    foreign_id: patient.foreign_id
                },
                {
                    onConflict: 'id, (source, foreign_id)' // herein lies the problem,
                }
            )
            .select()
            .single();

The above code of course throws an error:
{
    "code": "PGRST100",
    "details": "unexpected \"(\" expecting field name (* or [a..z0..9_$])",
    "hint": null,
    "message": "\"failed to parse on_conflict parameter (id, (source, foreign_id))\" (line 1, column 5)"
}

Since Supabase adds brackets, so i tried to escape them:
onConflict: 'id), (source, foreign_id' 


Which escapes correctly, but to no avail again:
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "patients_source_foreign_id_unique"

I did not find mention of this in the documentation, I am trying to satisfy two constrains, not two columns in the same constraint!
